# ANDROID Ratchet slider not smooth

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview, ratchet-2

I've got a webview that I'm displaying that has a couple of Ratchet slider components. I'm noticing that they're nearly un-usable because they'll jerk and jump around as I'm trying to scroll through the options.

Has anyone seen this before? Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

I haven't seen this issue on iOS, only Android.

Here is a link to the Ratchet [documentation](http://goratchet.com/components/#sliders).